# Converting timestamp value in 24Hours time format in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I was trying to convert one string value to desired 24 hours timestamp value. But its not converting. Its always showing 12 Hours timestamp format in redshift.

Ex:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP  ('Jan 22, 2024 1:06:19 PM','Mon DD, YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ;
```

**Output:**

```
2024-01-22 01:06:19+00
```

But the expected output I am looking for is:

```
2024-01-22 13:06:19
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert 12 hours to 24 hours :

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP('Jan 22, 2024 1:06:19 PM','Mon DD, YYYY HH24:MI:SS PM') ;
```

Results :

```
2024-01-22 13:06:19+00
```

To get it in the Format *YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS* :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP ('Jan 22, 2024 1:06:19 PM', 'Mon DD, YYYY HH24:MI:SS PM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Results :

```
2024-01-22 13:06:19
```

> This has been tested with PostgreSQL. Given that Amazon Redshift is
> built upon PostgreSQL, it is highly probable that it will also work on
> Redshift.

[Demo on postgresql](https://dbfiddle.uk/E0ndEz_T)